# golang type conversion after type assertion

Tags: types, go

Take these two bits of code:

1. http://play.golang.org/p/Oh6xNm2dRK

```
func main() {
    var media interface{}
    media = "boo"
    media = media.(string)
    fmt.Println([]byte(media))
}
```

2. http://play.golang.org/p/Vd-6AGCBKQ

```
func main() {
    media := "boo"
    fmt.Println([]byte(media))
}
```

In 1. the media is first created as the empty interface and then type asserted to a string.
In 2. the media is a string.

Both try to convert the media to a byte array, why the difference? Aren't they both strings by that time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one doesn't change the type of `media`, which is already defined as `interface{}`. You need to set it to a new string variable:

```
func main() {
    var media interface{}
    media = "boo"
    x := media.(string)
    fmt.Println([]byte(x))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/QB3ey_e3io

or do it inline:

```
func main() {
    var media interface{}
    media = "boo"
    fmt.Println([]byte(media.(string)))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/RJqBJ4telB

Comment: Ah that makes sense since a variable can only hold one type. I was thinking in dynamic language terms where you can reuse the variable for a different type, thanks !!